# Object not update by function in the same service Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I create a function (callPlayerData) for replace data in object (playerData) by data from database.

The function and the object is in the same service :

```
import  { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

interface PlayerData {
    name: string,
    level: number,
    truc: number,
    xp: number,
    xp_max: number,
    vie: number,
    vie_max: number
}

@Injectable()
export class PlayerService {
    constructor(private http: Http){
    }

    playerId = null;

    playerData: PlayerData = {
        name : "unwn",
        level : 5,
        truc : 36,
        xp: 0,
        xp_max: 0,
        vie: 0,
        vie_max: 0
    };

    callPlayerData(callback) {
        let that = this,
        loader = document.getElementById("loader");
        loader.style.display = "block";

        this.http.post(`api/gameData`, {id : that.playerId})
        .subscribe(response => {
            let gameData = JSON.parse(response.text()),
            item = 0;

            for (const key in gameData) {
                if (that.playerData[key]) {
                    that.playerData[key] = gameData[key];
                }
                item++;
                if(item === Object.keys(gameData).length) {
                    //that.playerData = Object.assign(JSON.parse(response.text()));
                    console.log(that.playerData);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        loader.style.display = "none";
                        callback();
                    }, 400);
                }
            }
        }, error => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
        });
    }
}
```

The console.log(that.playerData) at the end of the ForIn return the data updated but I have another console.log() in component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { PlayerService } from '../../player.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'stats-section',
  templateUrl: './stats.component.html'
})
export class StatsComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router, private player: PlayerService) {
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.player.playerData);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.player.playerData);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

This console.log() return the initial data of the object and not the data updated by the function.

Any ideas how to get the updated data in my component ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: You didn't write a single line of code to change the playerData of service. You just get playerData two times. You didn't performed any task to change your playerData.

Comment: Okay, if I understand what you told me, I duplicate playerData and I change the duplicate version. So the playerData of service is never update.

Comment: This is very messy. You're using a callback inside a `for...in` iterator (so it could be called more than once) but you guard against that using a `setTimeout`. Don't do that. Instead, `return this.http.post(...)` and then do the work you need inside that function, but don't call a callback, just `return` inside that. Then...where is `callPlayerData` even invoked? Wherever that is, do `this.player.callPlayerData(playerData).subscribe(newPlayerData => this.playerData = newPlayerData, error => errorHandler())` like a usual Observable.

Comment: @msanford I did what you said, I added in my function `return this.http.post('api/gameData', {id : that.playerId})` and I changed the call of the function by `this.player.callPlayerData().subscribe(newPlayerData => this.player.playerData = newPlayerData.json());`. The function return the good data but this.player.playerData is not updated out of function... I don't understand why